# I can't set states value in fetching api Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I am trying to create an infinite scroll by setting lazyload but I can't set the states each times in postData functions.

I can see the arr array works properly but it doesn't be setted in setCards(arr). I can't see the update in Devtolls Component Tools

If you have any idea I appriciated..

```
const postData = async (searchInputValue,payload) => {
    const response =  await fetch("https://smarty.kerzz.com:4004/api/mock/getFeed", {
        body: JSON.stringify(payload),
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            Apikey: "bW9jay04ODc3NTU2NjExMjEyNGZmZmZmZmJ2",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        method: "POST"
        })
    const data = await response.json()
    let arr =[...cards]
    console.log(cards)
    data.response.forEach((item, idx)=>{
       arr.push(item)

    })
    console.log(arr)  //[]
    setCards(arr)
    let a = counter + 1
    let new_payload = payload;
    new_payload.skip += 10*a
    setPayload(new_payload)
    setCounter(a)
 }

useEffect(()=>{
 // İlk yükleme sırasında lokasyon verisini alıp fonksiyonu çağırıyoruz. Aldığımız lokasyon 
verisine göre işlemlere devam edeceğiz.
findLocation();
window.addEventListener('scroll' , ()=>{
  let screen_height = window.innerHeight;
  let scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  var body = document.body,
  html = document.documentElement;

  var body_heigth = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
                    html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );
  
  if(scrollTop + 1 > body_heigth - screen_height && isloading === false && checked === false){ 
    setIsloading(true)
    postData(searchInputValue , payload)
  }
})
},[])
```

Comment: Where are you declaring the `cards` state? It's not in your code.

Comment: I just didn't write it but @Nice_books has told the true answer for my problem already. Tnx for help

Answer (score 2):

> If the new state is computed using the previous state, you can pass a function to setState. The function will receive the previous value, and return an updated value.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

Example:

```
setCounter((counter)=>(counter+1))
setCards((cards)=>(cards.concat(data.response)))
```

Do the same for `setPayload`.

Comment: You are the GOAT. Tnx brother.