# Could I fetch and filter only data that i need to single page at a time?

Tags: reactjs, filter, fetch

I'm hard stuck... I'm trying to filter products inside getProducts function, is that posible?  I want to read query params and filter with that informacion. This is my code:

```
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ProductCard } from './ProductCard';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import queryString from 'query-string';
import { SearchFilter } from '../../components/Search/SearchFilter';

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import {
  faChevronCircleLeft,
  faChevronCircleRight,
} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

import axios from 'axios';


export const ProductsList = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { q = '' } = queryString.parse(location.search); // search query
  const { c = '' } = queryString.parse(location.search); // category query
  const { i = 0 } = queryString.parse(location.search); // index query (pagination)

  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(0);
  const productsPerPage = 20;

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    const getProducts = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get('/casacarinaDataProductos.json');
      const { data } = res;
      getByCategory(data);
      getByDescription(data);
      // getByIndex(data);
      setIsLoading(false);
    };
    getProducts();
  }, [q, i, c]); //  eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

If I do products.filter the array at this moment is empty. Before start fetching data I imported json, but I want to do fetch because I could detect when the data is loading

```
  const getByCategory = (data) => {
    if (c !== '') {
      setProducts(
        data.filter(
          (oneData) => oneData.LISTA.toLowerCase() === c.toLowerCase()
        )
      );
    }
  };

  const getByDescription = (data) => {
    if (q !== '') {
      setProducts(
        data.filter((oneData) =>
          oneData.DESCRIPCION.toLowerCase().includes(q.toLowerCase())
        )
      );
    }
  };

 const getByIndex = () => {
    setProducts(products.slice(i, i + productsPerPage));
  };

  const previousPage = () => {
    if (currentPage > 0) {
      setCurrentPage(currentPage - productsPerPage);
      navigate(`/productos/busqueda?q=${q}&c=${c}&i=${currentPage}`);
      console.log('previous');
    }
  };

  const nextPage = () => {
    if (products.length > currentPage + productsPerPage) {
      setCurrentPage(currentPage + productsPerPage);
      navigate(`/productos/busqueda?q=${q}&c=${c}&i=${currentPage}`);
      console.log('next');
    }
  };
```

```
  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>Loading...</h4>
      </div>
    );
  } else if (products.length >= 1) {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchFilter />
        {/* <div className='productsList__bannerDiv'>
        <img
          className='productsList__banner'
          src={`/assets/banners/${params.title}Banner.jpg`}
          alt='banner'
        />
      </div> */}
        <div className='productsList__parentDiv'>
          <div className='productsList__gridDiv'>
            {products.map((product) => (
              <ProductCard key={product.CODIGO} {...product} />
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='productList__pagination'>
          <button onClick={previousPage}>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faChevronCircleLeft} />
          </button>
          <button onClick={nextPage}>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faChevronCircleRight} />
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <h4>No results</h4>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code? What's your desired result and What you got?

Comment: @AjayRaja I want that when query params change the function getProducts do fetch and filter products. I could filter by category or query search, but not both at the same time.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73449653/i-cant-set-states-value-in-fetching-api-reactjs/73449730#73449730

Answer (score 0):

> If the new state is computed using the previous state, you can pass a function to setState. The function will receive the previous value, and return an updated value.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

Example:

```
setProducts(products => products.slice(i, i + productsPerPage));
setCurrentPage(currentPage => currentPage - productsPerPage);
```